# how can I fix this interaction of the dialogue package and the textgreek package?

Tags: babel, greek, dialogue

I'm trying to use the dialogue package and the textgreek package together, and something is going wrong. I'll confess I'm not super-familiar with either package, so it may be something obvious that I'm missing.

The code below gives me a bunch of invalid UTF-8 byte errors and then claims there's something missing when I end the dialogue. If I cut the attributions (`\textgreek{\speak{ΖΗΝΟΘΕΜΙΣ}}` and `\textgreek{\speak{ΔΙΚΑΙΟΠΟΛΙΣ}}`) then the invalid UTF-8 byte errors disappear but I still get the error that something is missing.

Any thoughts about how I can fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek.polytoniko,english]{babel}
\usepackage{dialogue}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{τὸ μὲν οὖν πλοῖον πλεῖ, ὁ δὲ Ζηνόθεμις πρὸς τὴν γῆν βλέπει. τί ὁρᾷ ὁ Ζηνόθεμις; ὁ Ζηνόθεμις ὁρᾷ τήν τε ἀκρόπολιν καὶ τὸν Παρθενῶνα. ἔπειτα δὲ ὅ τε Δικαιόπολις καὶ ὁ κυβερνήτης πρὸς τὴν γῆν βλέπουσιν. τί ὁρῶσιν ὁ Δικαιόπολις καὶ ὁ κυβερνήτης; καὶ ὁ Δικαιόπολις καὶ ὁ κυβερνήτης την τε ἀκρόπολιν ὁρῶσι καὶ τὸν Παρθενῶνα. ἐξαίφνης ὅ τε Δικαιόπολις καὶ ὁ κυβερνήτης ψόφον ἀκούουσιν.}

\begin{dialogue}
\textgreek{\speak{ΖΗΝΟΘΕΜΙΣ}} \direct{pointing to the land} \textgreek{δεῦρο ἐλθέ, ὦ Δικαιόπολι, καὶ βλέπε. ἐγὼ γὰρ τὴν ἀκρόπολιν ὁρῶ. ἆρα καὶ σὺ τὴν ἀκρόπολιν ὁρᾷς;}
\textgreek{\speak{ΔΙΚΑΙΟΠΟΛΙΣ}} \direct{peering towards the land} \textgreek{ποῦ ἐστιν ἡ ἀκρόπολις; ἐγὼ γὰρ τὴν ἀκρόπολιν οὐχ ὁρῶ.}
\end{dialogue}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should switch the order of \speak and \textgreek. At second you need to redefine a command as the dialogue package uses the primitive \lowercase which simply doesn't work with greek:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek.polytoniko,english]{babel}
\usepackage{dialogue}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\renewcommand*\DialogueLabel [1] {%
  \scshape\MakeLowercase{#1}:\hfil
}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{τὸ μὲν οὖν πλοῖον πλεῖ, ὁ δὲ Ζηνόθεμις πρὸς τὴν γῆν βλέπει. τί ὁρᾷ 
ὁ Ζηνόθεμις; ὁ Ζηνόθεμις ὁρᾷ τήν τε ἀκρόπολιν καὶ τὸν Παρθενῶνα. ἔπειτα δὲ ὅ 
τε Δικαιόπολις καὶ ὁ κυβερνήτης πρὸς τὴν γῆν βλέπουσιν. τί ὁρῶσιν ὁ 
Δικαιόπολις καὶ ὁ κυβερνήτης; καὶ ὁ Δικαιόπολις καὶ ὁ κυβερνήτης την τε 
ἀκρόπολιν ὁρῶσι καὶ τὸν Παρθενῶνα. ἐξαίφνης ὅ τε Δικαιόπολις καὶ ὁ κυβερνήτης 
ψόφον ἀκούουσιν.} 

\begin{dialogue}
\speak{\textgreek{ΖΗΝΟΘΕΜΙΣ}} \direct{pointing to the land} \textgreek{δεῦρο 
ἐλθέ, ὦ Δικαιόπολι, καὶ βλέπε. ἐγὼ γὰρ τὴν ἀκρόπολιν ὁρῶ. ἆρα καὶ σὺ τὴν 
ἀκρόπολιν ὁρᾷς;} \speak{\textgreek{ΔΙΚΑΙΟΠΟΛΙΣ}} \direct{peering towards the 
land} \textgreek{ποῦ ἐστιν ἡ ἀκρόπολις; ἐγὼ γὰρ τὴν ἀκρόπολιν οὐχ ὁρῶ.} 
\end{dialogue}

\end{document}
```

[image]